# Accessing Json values Python

Tags: python, json, key-value

I have a json file, and i am trying to access the value, but i keep getting an error that says "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"

This is the Json data.

```
{'sentiment': '{\n  "0": {\n    "comment": "Chibok schoolgirls were swapped for 5 Boko Haram commanders \n    "username": "@NigeriaNewsdesk:, @todayng", \n    "score": 0.0\n  }\n}'}
```

data = val['sentiment']
printing data returns this back to me

```
{
 "0": {
  "comment": "Chibok schoolgirls were swapped for 5 Boko Haram commanders", 
  "username": "@NigeriaNewsdesk:, @todayng", 
  "score": 0.0
 }
}
```

But when i try to access the key/value pairs, i get an error 
for records in data:
    print(records["0"]["username"])

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Any idea why i am getting these errors? Thanks

Comment: What is `records`? I believe you want `print(data["0"]["username"])`.

Comment: Firstly the value of "sentiment" key is string and not a dict object. Secondly, it is not even a valid JSON string. You should fix the logic where you are storing this value. Probably store it as a dict or at least as valid JSON string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the json you posted, `sentiment` stores a json string, not a json object. You need to parse the json - e.g. `json.loads(val['sentiment'])`, or store the json as a json object.

Comment: it won't work because the *so called* JSON string mentioned in the question is having incorrect format